# Retraining existing base BERT model with additional data

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub

I have generated new Base BERT model(**dataset1_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12**) using **cased_L-12_H-768_A-12** as trained multi label classification from [biobert-run_classifier](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert/blob/master/run_classifier.py)

I need to add more additional data as **dataset2** and the model should be **dataset2_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12**

Is [tensorflow-hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_image_retraining) help this to resolve my problem?

Model training life cycle will be like this below,

> cased_L-12_H-768_A-12 => dataset1 => dataset1_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12
>
> dataset1_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12 => dataset2 =>
> dataset2_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow Hub is a platform for sharing pre-trained model pieces or whole models, and an API to facilitate this sharing. In TF 1.x, this API was a stand-alone API and in TF 2.x this API (SavedModel: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) is part of the core TF API.

In the proposed training life-cycle example, using SavedModel to save relevant model between the training steps could simplify pipeline architecture design. Alternatively, you could use coding examples available as part of the TF Model Garden to perform this pre-training: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/nlp.

Comment: dataset1_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12 has finished training nearly 4 days (without GPU), restoring from checkpoint means,So dataset2_model_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12 model has trained data's for both dataset1 and dataset2 ?